# Magento grid in admin module doesn't load after update from 1.3 to 1.5

Tags: php, magento, grid, version, admin

this question may look a little like these:
[Magento Grid Container Block not loading grid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5716580/magento-grid-container-block-not-loading-grid)
[Grid doesn't appear in custom admin module in Magento](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5604451/grid-doesnt-appear-in-custom-admin-module-in-magento)
 but it isn't the same issue, I believe.

I'm not the admin in this magento store, I only do some support/bugfix work on it. Server had Magento v1.3 installed, and there was a group of custom modules (I don't even know what were they for :P) written for it. Everything worked fine until someone updated Magento to v1.5. Every module had a grid with some data in it.

After updating, the grids stopped showing up, so pages where there were grids, are now blank, only the rest of admin panel (menu, etc.).

I guess modules were written for 1.3 and there is some common cause for them to disappear after update. I don't think that any core files were edited. Did you ever encounter such problem? If yes, can you give me any hint about how to bite this problem?

Cheers,
Maćko

Answer (score 0):

Grid.js has changed between 1.3 and 1.5. You may want to make sure that it is being loaded (Firebug) and then from where. It may be that a module is specifying a different version of the standard grid module.

Try going into admin - system - configuration - advanced and disabling all of the 3rd party add-on modules as that might bring it back to life.

Comment: I didn't specify that all other grids are fine, so it's just these third party modules that aren't don't show grids. Sorry for being not specific and thanks for reply!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6569386/approach-on-changing-row-color-on-orders-grid-in-admin - this shows how to use a custom grid js file by unloading the default grid.js and loading another. You could try a similar trick in your custom modules to load up 1.3 js files.